# n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action) returns value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

```
episodes = 10
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = random.choice([0,1])
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
```

The line n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action) returns this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 10
      8     env.render()
      9     action = random.choice([0,1])
---> 10     n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
     11     score+=reward
     12 print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

This code appears in a tutorial video and seems to work but always returns this error for me.

```
import os
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
```

```
environment_name = "CartPole-v0"
```

```
env = gym.make(environment_name)
```

```
episodes = 10
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = random.choice([0,1])
        n_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

More recent `gym` versions use a 5-tuple representing the output of `env.step(action)`, namely `state`, `reward`, `terminated`, `truncated`, and `info`. The `truncated` is a boolean that represents unexpected endings of the environment, such as a time limit or a non-existent state. The consequences are the same, the agent-environment loop should end.

Thus what you would actually want to do is:

```
while not (done or truncated):
    env.render()
    action = random.choice([0,1])
    n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    score+=reward
print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
```

Comment: I solved the issue myself, the problem is that I am on a higher version of openai gym, which is what causes these older programs to break

Comment: Thats exactly what I... nevermind. Glad you found out!